# Upgrading Windows yeilds empty shape files

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

I have a script I have been running in Windows 10 for quite some time and it has been working flawlessly. What it does is irrelevant, you can probably figure out by reading the code, but to conclude it it would be to say that it extract certain slopes in certain aspects.

After a major power out the main drive crashed and I had to reinstall Windows, I thought upgrading to Windows 11 would be a good idea. However, now that I am running the script on Windows 11 the shapefiles produced are empty. There are no errors reported.

Script:

```
from os.path import join, normpath
import os, shutil
from datetime import datetime
import time
from pushbullet import Pushbullet

print("Start point:", datetime.now())

pb = Pushbullet("xx")

path_start = normpath(r'H:\\GIS\\worklayers0\\')
path_temp = normpath(r'H:\\GIS\\templayers0\\')
path_temp2 = normpath(r'H:\\GIS\\temp2layers0\\')
path_end = normpath(r'H:\\GIS\\resultlayers0\\')

slope_list = [4, 4.9, 5.9, 7.1, 8.2, 10, 11.8, 13.8, 15.7, 17.9, 20.6, 25]
aspect_list_1 = [[0, 15], [15,30], [30, 45], [45, 60], [60, 75], [75, 90], [90, 105], [105, 120], [120, 135], [135, 150], [150, 165], [165, 180]]
aspect_list_2 = [[180, 195], [195, 210], [210, 225], [225, 240], [240, 255], [255, 270], [270, 285], [285, 300], [300, 315], [315, 330], [330, 345], [345, 360]]

for filename in os.listdir(path_temp):
    file_path = os.path.join(path_temp, filename)
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(file_path) or os.path.islink(file_path):
            os.unlink(file_path)
        elif os.path.isdir(file_path):
            shutil.rmtree(file_path)
    except:
        pass

for filename in os.listdir(path_temp2):
    file_path = os.path.join(path_temp2, filename)
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(file_path) or os.path.islink(file_path):
            os.unlink(file_path)
        elif os.path.isdir(file_path):
            shutil.rmtree(file_path)
    except:
        pass
    
for filename in os.listdir(path_end):
    file_path = os.path.join(path_end, filename)
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(file_path) or os.path.islink(file_path):
            os.unlink(file_path)
        elif os.path.isdir(file_path):
            shutil.rmtree(file_path)
    except:
        pass

files = os.listdir(path_start)

for index, file in enumerate(files):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path_start, file), os.path.join(path_start, ''.join([str(index), '.tif'])))

for number in range(3):
    
    processing.run("native:slope", {'INPUT':path_start+'\\'+str(number)+'.tif','Z_FACTOR':1,'OUTPUT':path_temp+'\\'+'slope_'+str(number)+'.tif'})
    processing.run("native:aspect", {'INPUT':path_start+'\\'+str(number)+'.tif','Z_FACTOR':1,'OUTPUT':path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_'+str(number)+'.tif'})
    
    processing.run("gdal:merge", {'INPUT':[path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_'+str(number)+'.tif',path_temp+'\\'+'slope_'+str(number)+'.tif'],'PCT':True,'SEPARATE':True,'NODATA_INPUT':None,'NODATA_OUTPUT':None,'OPTIONS':'','EXTRA':'','DATA_TYPE':5,'OUTPUT':path_temp+'\\'+'merge_'+str(number)+'.tif'})
        
    processing.run("native:pixelstopolygons", {'INPUT_RASTER':path_temp+'\\'+'merge_'+str(number)+'.tif','RASTER_BAND':1,'FIELD_NAME':'ASPECT','OUTPUT':path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
    processing.run("native:createspatialindex", {'INPUT':path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
        
    processing.run("native:pixelstopolygons", {'INPUT_RASTER':path_temp+'\\'+'merge_'+str(number)+'.tif','RASTER_BAND':2,'FIELD_NAME':'SLOPE','OUTPUT':path_temp+'\\'+'slope_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
    processing.run("native:createspatialindex", {'INPUT':path_temp+'\\'+'slope_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
        
    processing.run("native:joinattributesbylocation", {'INPUT':path_temp+'\\'+'slope_'+str(number)+'.shp','PREDICATE':[5],'JOIN':path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_'+str(number)+'.shp','JOIN_FIELDS':[],'METHOD':0,'DISCARD_NONMATCHING':False,'PREFIX':'','OUTPUT':path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
    aspect_slope_layer = iface.addVectorLayer(path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_'+str(number)+'.shp', "", "ogr")
        
    
    for i in range(len(slope_list)):
        aspect_list_1[i].append(slope_list[i])
    
    for i in range(len(slope_list)):
        aspect_list_2[i].append(slope_list[::-1][i])
        
    for aspect_interval in aspect_list_1:
            start = aspect_interval[0] 
            end = aspect_interval[1]
            slope_loop = aspect_interval[2]
            aspect_slope_layer.selectByExpression('"ASPECT">'+str(start)+' and "ASPECT"<='+str(end)+' and "SLOPE">='+str(slope_loop))
            QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(aspect_slope_layer, str(path_temp)+'\\'+'aspect_slope_'+str(start)+'-'+str(end)+'_'+str(number)+'.shp', "UTF-8", aspect_slope_layer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile", onlySelected=True)
            processing.run("native:createspatialindex", {'INPUT':str(path_temp)+'\\'+'aspect_slope_'+str(start)+'-'+str(end)+'_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
            
    for aspect_interval in aspect_list_2:
            start = aspect_interval[0] 
            end = aspect_interval[1]
            slope_loop = aspect_interval[2]
            aspect_slope_layer.selectByExpression('"ASPECT">'+str(start)+' and "ASPECT"<='+str(end)+' and "SLOPE">='+str(slope_loop))
            QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(aspect_slope_layer, str(path_temp)+'\\'+'aspect_slope_'+str(start)+'-'+str(end)+'_'+str(number)+'.shp', "UTF-8", aspect_slope_layer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile", onlySelected=True)
            processing.run("native:createspatialindex", {'INPUT':str(path_temp)+'\\'+'aspect_slope_'+str(start)+'-'+str(end)+'_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
    
    processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':[path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_0-15_'+str(number)+'.shp',path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_345-360_'+str(number)+'.shp'],'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':str(path_temp2)+'\\'+'1_aspect_slope_int_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
    processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':[path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_15-30_'+str(number)+'.shp',path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_330-345_'+str(number)+'.shp'],'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':str(path_temp2)+'\\'+'2_aspect_slope_int_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
    processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':[path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_30-45_'+str(number)+'.shp',path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_315-330_'+str(number)+'.shp'],'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':str(path_temp2)+'\\'+'3_aspect_slope_int_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
    processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':[path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_45-60_'+str(number)+'.shp',path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_300-315_'+str(number)+'.shp'],'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':str(path_temp2)+'\\'+'4_aspect_slope_int_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
    processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':[path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_60-75_'+str(number)+'.shp',path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_285-300_'+str(number)+'.shp'],'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':str(path_temp2)+'\\'+'5_aspect_slope_int_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
    processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':[path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_75-90_'+str(number)+'.shp',path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_270-285_'+str(number)+'.shp'],'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':str(path_temp2)+'\\'+'6_aspect_slope_int_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
    processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':[path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_90-105_'+str(number)+'.shp',path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_255-270_'+str(number)+'.shp'],'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':str(path_temp2)+'\\'+'7_aspect_slope_int_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
    processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':[path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_105-120_'+str(number)+'.shp',path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_240-255_'+str(number)+'.shp'],'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':str(path_temp2)+'\\'+'8_aspect_slope_int_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
    processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':[path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_120-135_'+str(number)+'.shp',path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_225-240_'+str(number)+'.shp'],'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':str(path_temp2)+'\\'+'9_aspect_slope_int_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
    processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':[path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_135-150_'+str(number)+'.shp',path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_210-225_'+str(number)+'.shp'],'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':str(path_temp2)+'\\'+'10_aspect_slope_int_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
    processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':[path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_150-165_'+str(number)+'.shp',path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_195-210_'+str(number)+'.shp'],'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':str(path_temp2)+'\\'+'11_aspect_slope_int_'+str(number)+'.shp'})
    processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':[path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_165-180_'+str(number)+'.shp',path_temp+'\\'+'aspect_slope_180-195_'+str(number)+'.shp'],'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':str(path_temp2)+'\\'+'12_aspect_slope_int_'+str(number)+'.shp'})


    for i in range(1,13):
        processing.run("native:createspatialindex", {'INPUT':str(path_temp2)+'\\'+str(i)+'_aspect_slope_int_'+str(number)+'.shp'})     
    
    QgsProject.instance().removeAllMapLayers()

merge_list = os.listdir(path_temp2)

for i in range(1,13):
    check = str(i)+'_'
    name_ext_matches = []
    name_matches = [idx for idx in merge_list if idx.lower().startswith(check.lower())]
    
    for file in name_matches:
        
        if file.endswith('.shp'):
            name_ext_matches.append(file)
            
        matches = [path_temp2 +'\\'+ x for x in name_ext_matches]
            
    processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':matches,'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':str(path_temp)+'\\'+str(i)+'_aspect_slope_int_int.shp'})
    processing.run("native:createspatialindex", {'INPUT':str(path_temp)+'\\'+str(i)+'_aspect_slope_int_int.shp'})    
    processing.run("native:refactorfields", {'INPUT':str(path_temp)+'\\'+str(i)+'_aspect_slope_int_int.shp','FIELDS_MAPPING':[{'expression': '"SLOPE"','length': 20,'name': 'SLOPE','precision': 8,'sub_type': 0,'type': 2,'type_name': 'integer'},{'expression': '"ASPECT"','length': 20,'name': 'ASPECT','precision': 8,'sub_type': 0,'type': 4,'type_name': 'int8'}],'OUTPUT':str(path_end)+'\\'+str(i)+'_aspect_slope.shp'})
    processing.run("native:createspatialindex", {'INPUT':str(path_end)+'\\'+str(i)+'_aspect_slope.shp'}) 
  

phone = pb.devices[0]
push = pb.push_note("Wakie wakie!", "All done with extracting the slopes.")
print("Notifications sent!")
print("Done!")
print("End point:", datetime.now())
```

Comment: This is unlikely related to a windows update. I would rather assume some of the input files are not there, or you're missing dependent libraries.

Comment: The input files are all there. If there was a library missing, wouldn't this raise an error?

Comment: Also, I don't see any libraries imported which aren't natively in Python, or am I wrong?

Comment: (except for the obvious - pushbullet)

Comment: I've never worked with pyqgis, but the calls to processing.run could require something as well.

Comment: Those are all native when using the console in QGIS, but sure, in a normal case they would need an imported library. In any case, this was not an issue before the crash.

Comment: I'm assuming that you reinstalled QGIS and GDAL using osgeo4w? - I suspect adding some print statements to see what's going in would help

Comment: I might be totally wrong, but by installing QGIS you also get osgeo4w (shell). There's no getting osgeo4w without installing QGIS. Also when installing QGIS you "automatically" get GDAL as well...?

Comment: The GDAL version installed is 3.7.2 (released 23/09/06)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong. It was the version that didn't support my script.
I was using 3.26.2 before upgrading to Win11. Running on Win11 I have been using 3.28.
Could there be some change in the GDAL which shows in the scripts? In any case, it's weird since it raises no errors.